# adding class to <a href> if nested ul

Tags: jquery

I have the following menu

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Main1</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Main2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and im trying, though JS to add a class to the `<a href>` if there is a parent menu, so that my menu becomes like this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Main1</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="hassubmenu">Main2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$("li").has( "ul" ).addClass('contains-sub-menu');
```

only add the class to the `<li>`, how to add it to `<a>` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@DCI STUDIOS LTD**  you are too close to right solution what you tried. You just missed to check first link and then add class to that link

Do like below:-

```
$('li').has('ul').find('a:first').addClass('hassubmenu');
```

Working snippet:-

```js
$('li').has('ul').find('a:first').addClass('hassubmenu');
```

```css
.hassubmenu{ /*to show you that code worked*/
  color:green;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> <a href="index.html">Main1</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#">Main2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
       <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Main3</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">Main4</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
       <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

***A better solution is what i previously provided (after modification what suggested by @A. Wolff):-***

```
$('li ul').parent().children('a').addClass('hassubmenu');
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$('li ul').parent().children('a').addClass('hassubmenu');
```

```css
.hassubmenu{ /*to show you that code worked*/
  color:green;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> <a href="index.html">Main1</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#">Main2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
       <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Main3</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">Main4</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
       <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: @N.Ivanov I think it's bad idea to down voting for a simple problem!

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh +1 for your answer, because it's shorter than mine.

Comment: Would be better imho: `$('li ul').parent().children('a').addClass('hassubmenu');`